# Unable to unlink files in php

Tags: php

I am currently trying to unlink uploaded files in PHP. To do so, i am calling an ajax function which passes a relative filepath to another page, which deletes the file.

However, i keep getting the error

```
unlink(..filepath...) no such files or directory in C:.....
```

Upon looking around, i found that unlink might encounter issues with relative file paths, so i tried converting the relative filepahts to an absolute one by using

```
$newfilepath=realpath($filepath);
```

but when i tried echoing the results of the realpath to check if it executed successfully, i got the result

```
bool(false)
```

When i checked the manual,i saw

```
Note:
The running script must have executable permissions on all directories in the 
hierarchy, otherwise realpath() will return FALSE.
```

When the files were being uploaded, they were saved to a directory with CHMOD 0644, which i guess is causing the problems. If so, is there any way to unlink the files?

P.S the files are being uploaded to my server by users of my website via the use of a form hence the CHMOD

EDIT:

Function:

```
function DeleteImageDP(){

    var itemid=$('#DisplayDeleteItemID').val();
    var file=$('#DisplayDeleteFilePath').val();
    var filepath=encodeURIComponent(file);
    var itempicid=$('#DisplayDeleteItemPicID').val();
    var cfm=confirm("Confirm deletion of picture? ( Note: Picture wil be deleted permanently.");
    if(cfm == true)
    {
        $.ajax({

        url:"delete/deletedp.php",
        type:"POST",
        data:"ItemID="+itemid+"&FilePath="+filepath+"&ItemPicID="+itempicid,
        success:function(){

            alert("Image successfully deleted.");
            $('#ImagePreviewDP').prop('src','').hide();
            $('#ImagePreviewDPValidate').val('');
            $('#DisplayDelete').hide();

            $('#ItemDetailsContainer').trigger('change');

        },
        error:function(){

            alert("Image could not be deleted due to an error.");

        }

        });
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }

};
```

Page called:

```
$bizid=$_SESSION['BizID'];
$itemid=$_POST['ItemID'];
$file=$_POST['FilePath'];
$filepath=realpath($file);
$itempicid=$_POST['ItemPicID'];
//empties dp field in items table
$delete=$cxn->prepare("UPDATE `Items` SET `ItemDP`=:deleted WHERE `BusinessID`=:bizid AND `ItemID`=:itemid");
$delete->bindValue(":bizid",$bizid);
$delete->bindValue(":itemid",$itemid);
$delete->bindValue(":deleted","NULL");
$delete->execute();
//removes from itempics
$deletepic=$cxn->prepare("DELETE  FROM `ItemPics` WHERE `BusinessID`=:bizid AND `ItemID`=:itemid AND `ItemPicID`=:itempicid AND `FilePath` LIKE :search");
$deletepic->bindValue(":search","%DP");
$deletepic->bindValue(":bizid",$bizid);
$deletepic->bindValue(":itemid",$itemid);
$deletepic->bindValue(":itempicid",$itempicid);
$deletepic->execute();

if($deletepic)
{
    unlink($filepath);
    return ( true );
}
else
{
    return ( false );
}
```

Comment: Please share your PHP code. `unlink()` doesn't struggle with relative paths so long as they're defined correctly. Remember, that they're relative to the **PHP file**, not the JS file performing the AJAX request. Judging by the errors you're getting, the path you're specifying is incorrect.

Comment: realpath() returns FALSE on failure, e.g. if the file does not exist. (from php.net/realpath) Probably the path is bad.

Comment: @LajosVeres The path is valid, because i am displaying an img using the filepath in it's src before calling the function.As the image is able to be displayed, the filepath should there be valid?

Comment: @BenM I've added my PHP code

Comment: @Kenneth.J as I said above, please bear in mind the path should be relative to the PHP file, not the HTML page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're getting the URL relative to your HTML page, but the actual PHP file handling the delete is one directory down (i.e. inside `/delete/`).

As such, you'll need to modify the relative URL on the PHP side to ensure it's locating the correct file.

Try updating your PHP file with the following code:

```
unlink('../'.$filepath);
```

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up.I tried refactoring my code, moving certain files into folders and i forgot that the file locations have changed